# `emacs` and `Emacs` start the same application?

Tags: macos, emacs

I am trying to understand how the shell is interpreting `emacs` and `Emacs`, and where it finds the application.

I can launch emacs by running

```
bash
emacs &
```

or

```bsh
Emacs &
```

in the terminal, and it looks to me like it is the same application (which is not the emacs shipped with the OS, which is at `/usr/bin/emacs`, but another one which I have installed, almost certainly with `emacsformacosx` though I am not sure how to verify this information).

My `PATH`:

```bsh
$ echo "$PATH"
/Users/antoine/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/antoine/.pyenv/shims:/Users/antoine/.local/bin:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Running

```bsh
which emacs
```

returns

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs
```

and

```bsh
which emacs
```

returns

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

Now if I look into the folder `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/`, I only see `Emacs` but no `emacs`:

```bsh
$ ls -1d /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/[eE]*
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-i386-10_5
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_10
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_5
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_7
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9
```

On the other hand, if I use `find`, I get a result `emacs`, but I don't understand where it comes from:

```bsh
$ find /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/ emacs | grep emacs
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//bin-x86_64-10_7/emacsclient
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//bin-i386-10_5/emacsclient
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//bin-x86_64-10_5/emacsclient
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//bin-x86_64-10_10/emacsclient
emacs
```

but I don't see this last `emacs` in the folder, so where should I be looking?

(In addition, I don't understand exactly what `find` does, as it returns outputs without the string "emacs" in it, so I filtered them with `grep`).

One last remark.
Previously I had a typo in my PATH (which I set in my `.profile`): I had

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOs
```

(note the lower case "s" in "MacOs" at the end) instead of

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS
```

But I did not get any error, not did it seem to make any difference to correct this type.  Namely, even with the type, `which emacs` happily returned `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOs/emacs` (with the typo) and `which Emacs` just as happily returned `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOs/Emacs` (again with the type).

So this suggests that `emacs` or `Emacs` are found somewhere else.

Comment: On MacOS, file names are case-insensitive by default. Perhaps that's what's causing this?

Comment: You've got to be kidding... Indeed, `eMacs` for example also works.  I am still wondering about the `emacs` appearing in the result of `find`, and the other mystery about the typo not seeming to have any impact.

Comment: Where were you when you typed that find command?  I think you actually wanted something like `find /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/ -name emacs` (note the `-name` argument).  If there was an `emacs` in the current directory when you ran the find command it does indeed print out `emacs` at the end given your command (at least on Linux it does).

Comment: I wish I remembered exactly where I ran the command.  I just tried from within `/usr/bin`, which contains the system's emacs, but the `find` command doesn't output anything.  Nice try, though.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? I didn't want to close it as unclear because this would just bounce it back to SO, but please edit your question down to what you actually want to know (ideally by considering that you now already know that macOS doesn't care so much about upper/lowercase in filenames by default, so some of the issues in your question are already explained).

Comment: Please don't include the answer in the post. You can "accept" a given answer (if it does answer the question) by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting arrows at the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default install of macOS uses a case-insensitive file system. This is true of both HFS+ installations of macOS 10.12 (Sierra) and earlier, as well as APFS installation of macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and later.

The use of a case-insensitive file systems means that files and folders can be reached with any mix of case in the name. The name used to create the file/folder is used verbatim when displaying the name of the file, but when you need to access it, you can mix it up:

```
$ touch myTeSt
$ ls
myTeSt
$ rm mytest
$
```

I.e. the case is displayed as "myTeSt" when running ls, but you can delete the file using "mytest", "MYTEST" or any variation thereof.

Naturally, this also extends to programs that you can then start using any variation of case inside the program name.

Note that it is possible to install macOS on a case-sensitive file system, where this does not apply, however it is not the default install.